# Alternative to Personal Blocklist for Safari

Tags: google

I’d want to filter a bunch of spammy sites from the search results on Google, just like the Personal Blocklist extension does on Chrome, is there an alternative to Google’s Personal Blocklist extension for Safari?

I’ve found [this](http://diairetis.jp/en/safariBlocklist) but seems outdated.

Answer (score 3):

Kind of late, but I hope it will help some people. I use [this script](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/1682-google-hit-hider-by-domain-search-filter-block-sites) with [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net), it works great on 10.11.3 / Safari 9.0.3.